# How to restore the state of p:dataTable before dialog reopen?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using the **PrimeFaces 3.5**. I have `p:dialog` in which is `p:dataTable`. This is used to pick the item from filtered list.

After selecting the item I'm hiding the dialog and de-rendering the data table. But after showing the dialog again and re-rendering the data table, the data table contains the rows from previous filtering, but the filters themselves are clear.

I'm using the **lazy data loading**, so the `values` point to `LazyDataModel`, and the `filteredValues` are not set.

I would like to have the dataTable again in default state, so that both filters and selected rows would be empty. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source, it looks like you can call `reset()` on an instance of `org.primefaces.component.datatable.Table` which will

1. Clear filtered values
2. Clear filters
3. Reset it's value

So you should obtain a reference to the client side datatable (either by value binding or walking the DOM from event) and call `table.reset()`